# Which Google Account set up the Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

i have a few different web sites w/ Analytics loaded on.    One site is not showing up in my analytics reports because i think it was set up by someone else working for me at the time.  I know the "UA-xxxx" code.   How do i find out which analytics account it is associated with so i can get in there to see the data and/or transfer elsewhere?

Comment: If possible you will need to contact the previous admin to provide you admin access. It's always a good idea to keep your list of trusted admins updated, and to have more than one at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to that account it will show up in your Google Analytics home screen (UA-ID is displayed next to the name of a property). If your Google Account has no access to the Analytics account then knowing the UA-ID won't help, you will not have access to the data.

Answer (score 0):

If the Analytic account is yours, you can go to "Admin", on the second column choose "Property settings". Now on property setting on left sidebar, choose your site and you can see the tracking code UA-ID